# How do I reference a "drop as zip" or a drop folder instead of the source when building in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm used to working with TeamCity so it might be that I should completely change my workflow, in that case answer with a suggestion of a new workflow instead.

In TeamCity I usually build and run unit tests as one build task (at every commit). Longer running tests are scheduled nightly and are run in the same way. So far I've manged to replicate the process in TFS. But on top of this I have a build task to deploy/publish a package. This is something I start manually once we are ready for it. This script references the artifact from a previous build (i.e. a drop folder or a drop zip in TFS).

[image: Image of the Download drop as zip button to clarify what I'm referencing]

I've read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx) article about deployment scripts but I can't find any information about how I can trigger them in TFS.

So the question in short: How do I reference a "drop as zip" or a drop folder instead of the source when building in TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "Get Specific Build" or the "Latest Successful Build" on a specific Build, and then you can refer to that build's drop location.
Using TFS API, getting latest one should look something like this:

```
using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")))
{
    var buildServer= tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
    var buildSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(teamProjectName, buildDefinition); 
    buildSpec.InformationTypes = null; 
    buildSpec.MinFinishTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-lastXHours); 
    buildSpec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1;
    buildSpec.QueryOrder = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
    buildSpec.Status=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildStatus.Succeeded;
    var buildDetails = buildServer.QueryBuilds(buildSpec).Builds; 
    if (buildDetails.Length ==1){var dropLocation= buildDetails[0].DropLocation; }    
    else { Console.WriteLine("No builds found." );}

}
```